# how to make internal link in org-mode case insensitive

Tags: emacs, hyperlink, org-mode

If I have a heading called "Heading1", I can link to it within the same org file with `[[Heading1]]`, but I'd also like `[[heading1]]` to link there as well. Is there a way to make links case insensitive? I could not find anything in org-mode [documentation](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Internal-links).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to using an older version org that was bundled with emacs. I downloaded the latest version from elpa and links became case insensitive. More info [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20441/how-to-make-internal-link-in-org-mode-case-insensitive)